# Discard content of logfile, keeping tail

Tags: bash, tail

I'm looking for a way how to discard content of the logfile, leaving only defined tail. In two steps it's quite easy:

```
tail -n1000 alert_migtst.log > alert_migtst.tail
mv -f alert_migtst.tail alert_migtst.log
```

Is there a way how to achieve the same with a single command, among other reasons to avoid possible loss of lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed`

```
sed -e :a -e '$q;N;1001,$D;ba' -i filename
```

- `-e` defines a script (command)
- `:a` defines a label
- `$q` defines an address (`$` end of file) and branches `q` to it
- `N` appends the next line of input to the pattern space
- `1001,$d` deletes all the line between 1001 and the end of file (because of the previous `N` they will be appended to the pattern space)
- `ba` branches to the label defined at the beginning

For example (last 3 lines of the file)

```
$ cat alert_migtst.log 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
$ sed -e :a -e '$q;N;4,$D;ba' -i alert_migtst.log 
$ cat alert_migtst.log 
7
8
9
```

Comment: Honestly, I hoped there will be some simple way like special command but maybe it's not so usual task as I thought. But this will work without additional tools, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [sponge](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) that you can install with the package `moreutils`. It allows you to redirect the output on the same file (else you delete it).

```
   tail -n1000 alert_migtst.log | sponge alert_migtst.log
```

As a normal rule do practice with all solutions that you find before using it on critical files.

Comment: I can't install additional packages just for single task so I'll go with sed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to test all that you can with _running files_ because e.g. with the method you used before you can miss some lines if are printed in the meanwhile you copy the temp file to the new one. I don't know how the system can handle with `sed` if the size will change meanwhile it acts. I don't know so in details `sponge` too :) but it seems to act in a more similar way you did before. ps> up-vote the `sed` answer it shows cure in the way is done.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the issues of the original solution, that's why I started looking for a better one.:-) I would up-vote but my new account has too low reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '1,-1000d|x' alert_migtst.log
```

1. `1,-1000` select all but last 1000 lines
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close